# Cloning bit-bucket repo with https using dockerfile.How to pass a password?

Tags: git, docker, github, dockerfile, git-clone

I have a dockerfile. In which i have to clone a repository from bitbucket using https url but **how am i suppose to pass a password to make the clone complete?** **And yes i tried ssh .it works but i need https clone for some shell script to run so that it should automatically accepts the password.**

Here is my docker command to clone repo:

**RUN git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/abc/xyz.git**

And here is the error i get while buildind docker file : \

**Cloning into 'newfolder'...
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@bitbucket.org': No such device or address**

MY build command is :

**sudo docker build --no-cache=true -t image:build .**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the password in the url as such:

```
git clone https://username:password@bitbucket.org/abc/xyz.git
```

If you don't want to hardcode the password in the dockerfile, you can pass it as a build arg.

```
ARG password
RUN git clone https://username:$password@bitbucket.org/abc/xyz.git
```

`sudo docker build --build-arg password=pass --no-cache=true -t image:build .`

Comment: i tried that but still i get following error :

Cloning into 'newfolder'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://username:@password123@bitbucket.org/abc/xyz.git/': Could not resolve host: password123@bitbucket.org

Comment: your password starts with @. It is being interpreted as a host. You need to escape the @ character by %40